# convert link (SEO mode) to Yii route link with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo, yii

### hi all,

i'm looking for a htaccess script that convert SEO friendly link in this case :

```
http://www.sitename.domain/content/categoryName/subCategoryName/contentId/contentName.html
```

to Yii (PHP Framework) route link in this case:

```
http://www.sitename.domain/index.php?r=content/view&id=contentId
```

and another question is , is it possible to use IF condition inside a htaccess file?

we have links that not want to use this rule !

at the end, thank you for your attention .

Comment: Why do you want to use the htaccess and not yii's build in url manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use url manager for this? Something along the lines of

```
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'urlManager'=>array(
        ...
        'content/<categoryName:\w+>/<subCategoryName:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<contentName:\w+>.html'=>'content/view',
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

What are the 'if' statements you want to have? If may be a case that you can apply those above the main rule so they get run first if the formatting is a little different?

Comment: no probs, there's a lot of good info here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url